# Force relationships from a node label X to a node label Y to have specific properties

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, schema

I'm aware that using the "relationship property existence constraint" available in Neo4j Enterprise I can force relationships of a given label to have some properties, for example:

(Relationships of label "LIKED" always have a "day" property)

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON ()-[like:LIKED]-() ASSERT exists(like.day)
```

But is it possible to force relationships from a node label X to a node label Y to have specific properties? An example of what I would like to do would be:

(Relationships of label "BOUGHT" from/to nodes label "Person" to/from nodes label "Book" always have a "day" property)

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person)-[bo:BOUGHT]-(b:Book) ASSERT exists(b.day)
```

But that isn't considered a valid Cypher command. Is there a way to achieve this effect at a schema level or would I need to implement it in the application layer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, It's not possible to achieve this effect at a schema level at the moment.

You need to figure it out, how to implement this in the application layer.

> If this `LIKED` relationship is different from other `LIKED`
>   relationship( i.e. LIKED relationship between other node labels pair)
>   then you can name it anything else and create **"relationship property
>   existence constraint"** on it.